# What are the advantages of using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my Django App as compared to EC2?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've built a simple blogging Django app for myself, and want to deploy it using AWS. After some research, it looks like my options for deployment are `Elastic Beanstalk` and `EC2`.

What are the advantages of using `Elastic Beanstalk` over `EC2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk adds a layer of abstraction over EC2. It manages autoscaling, a load balancer, an optional database, etc, for you. If you use plain EC2, and you need any of that, you need to manage those resources yourself. If you want to focus solely on building the website, Elastic Beanstalk should simplify some of your operations. Its cost is also not higher than plain EC2, you only pay for the underlying resources used on your stack. The disadvantage of Elastic Beanstalk is that it's less flexible than EC2. So, if you want to fine tune every single knob on your stack, you should probably go with EC2.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25956193/347777) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25956368/347777) expand the subject a little bit more.