# Deploying js app to AWS - EC2 or Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am pretty new to AWS, so please bear with me. I would like to deploy this [application](https://github.com/cncf/landscapeapp) into AWS. I had no problems running locally, but now I am little bit overwhelmed with the offered services. I dont need large storage, I dont use database, I simply need just a server. Is there any reason for me to consider Beanstalk or is it okay to use simple EC2? From what I have read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956193/difference-between-amazon-ec2-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk), it looks like Beanstalk adds a lot of useless stuff I would not ever use. Thanks for all your inputs.

Comment: " useless stuff " - what do you think is useless? You can customize it to not use what you don't want. Beanstalk is very popular because of what it gives your for free, and releases you from worrying about many things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would recommend using AWS EC2 to deploy your app because of the flexibility offered by EC2. They offered the free tier, so you can try and play around with the environment.  The EC2 instance is a remote Linux machine, so you can configure it as much as you like and very flexible.

If you have dockerize your app, you just simply need to copy the docker instance to your EC2 instance and simply host your server there. If you don't dockerize your app, you can just fetch from your repository and download all the dependencies first and your app should work just fine.